# Update Multiple User ExtensionAttributes by UPN

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

Looking to import UserPrincipalName and updates ExtensionAttributes 1-15

I currently have a script that works to update an individual UserPrincipalName ExtensionAttributes and works great.

```
 Set-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectId test@test.com -ExtensionName extensionattribute1 -ExtensionValue "stuff"
 Set-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectId test@test.com -ExtensionName extensionattribute2 -ExtensionValue "things"
 Set-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectId test@test.com -ExtensionName extensionattribute3 -ExtensionValue "stuff"
 Set-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectId test@test.com -ExtensionName extensionattribute4 -ExtensionValue "things"
 Set-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectId test@test.com -ExtensionName extensionattribute5 -ExtensionValue "test"
 Set-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectId test@test.com -ExtensionName extensionattribute6 -ExtensionValue "test"
 Set-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectId test@test.com -ExtensionName extensionattribute7 -ExtensionValue "test"
 Set-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectId test@test.com -ExtensionName extensionattribute8 -ExtensionValue "florida"
 Set-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectId test@test.com -ExtensionName extensionattribute9 -ExtensionValue "12444"
 Set-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectId test@test.com -ExtensionName extensionattribute10 -ExtensionValue "stuff"
 Set-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectId test@test.com -ExtensionName extensionattribute11 -ExtensionValue "things"
 Set-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectId test@test.com -ExtensionName extensionattribute12 -ExtensionValue "test"
 Set-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectId test@test.com -ExtensionName extensionattribute13 -ExtensionValue "test"
 Set-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectId test@test.com -ExtensionName extensionattribute14 -ExtensionValue "test"
 Set-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectId test@test.com -ExtensionName extensionattribute15 -ExtensionValue "test"
```

But as you can see can be time consuming if I have several users to update.

So I tried to create the following

```
$users = import-csv "C:\temp\womp.csv"

$users | ForEach-Object{

Set-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectId $_.extensionattribute1 (Get-AzureADUser -ObjectID $_.UserPrincipalName).objectID
Set-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectId $_.extensionattribute2 (Get-AzureADUser -ObjectID $_.UserPrincipalName).objectID
Set-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectId $_.extensionattribute3 (Get-AzureADUser -ObjectID $_.UserPrincipalName).objectID
Set-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectId $_.extensionattribute4 (Get-AzureADUser -ObjectID $_.UserPrincipalName).objectID
Set-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectId $_.extensionattribute5 (Get-AzureADUser -ObjectID $_.UserPrincipalName).objectID

}
```

But have gotten numerous of errors.

```
Set-AzureADUserExtension : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument
```

and

```
Get-AzureADUser : Error occurred while executing GetUser Code: Request_ResourceNotFound
```

Attached is a screenshot is my CSV setup:
[CSV Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3PpB.png)

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not understand what the `Set-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectId $_.extensionattribute1 (Get-AzureADUser -ObjectID $_.UserPrincipalName).objectID` mean in your script, I suppose you want to set the several extensions for all the users in your `.csv` file.

Besides, if we [create a new extension property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/using-extension-attributes-sample?view=azureadps-2.0#create-a-new-extension-property), the name should be like `extension_0380f0f700c040b5aa577c9268940b53_MyNewProperty`, why yours are `extensionattribute1`, `extensionattribute2`.

Try the script works for me, my sample just has two users and two extensions, the logic is the same, you could try it.

```
$users = import-csv "C:\Users\joyw\Desktop\testfile.csv"

$users | ForEach-Object{

Set-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectId $_.UserPrinciaplName -ExtensionName extension_242365dc795xxxxxfb73236a3_testex1 -ExtensionValue $_.extension_242365dc795xxxxxfb73236a3_testex1
Set-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectId $_.UserPrinciaplName -ExtensionName extension_242365dc795xxxxxfb73236a3_MyProp -ExtensionValue $_.extension_242365dc795xxxxxfb73236a3_MyProp


}
```

My `testfile.csv` file:

```
UserPrinciaplName,extension_242365dc795xxxxxfb73236a3_testex1,extension_242365dc795xxxxxfb73236a3_MyProp
leeliu@xxx.onmicrosoft.com,testvalue1,testvaule2
test@xxx.onmicrosoft.com,testv1,testv2
```

[image]

Check the result for the two users:

[image]

Comment: To answer your question, there are preset extensionattributes 1-15 that were on OnPrem AD and carried over to AzureAD. The only way you can view the ExtensionAttributes is by viewing in Microsoft Grap: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer and running the this command in GET. https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/test@test.com?$select=onpremisesextensionattributes it will then populate onpremextensionattributes. I was able to modify your script slightly and was able to update all extension attributes with no problems

Comment: @LarryDavid Got it, also glad it helps.